# Proxy server based on a specific region

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, proxy

I want to create an AWS EC2 instance with an IP address specific to a region. For example if it is Jackson, Mississippi, I want the instance to have an IP which belongs to that same region. If I use that IP as Proxy and go to whatismyip, it should always show Jackson, Mississippi area.

Comment: IP addresses do not "belong" to a location in the world. They are allocated to organisations, who can with them whatever they wish. There are various repositories that have attempted to map the location of IP addresses (eg GeoMind) but they are "after the fact". It's a bit like GPS -- you can locate where you are at the moment, but you are still free to move around.

Comment: Have you investigated anycast? You can use the same IP address in multiple places around the world, and routing will send traffic to the closest host with that address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. An EC2 instance is created in a region, and AWS has 12 regions as of now. See more about regions and endpoints here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

The closest region to Jackson, Mississippi is probably Ohio (us-east-2) or us-east-1, where you could provision your instances.

You can use AWS DirectConnect to link your data center to AWS and can probably achieve what you want, but I believe you don't wish to get there.